# How to access an element from a 2D array, with non-sequential row and column data - C#

Tags: c#, arrays, matrix, indexing, 2d

I need to access a text file containing some data gathered from the machine from two testing planes. One plane is vertical and creates rows that can be 1-180 degrees with 1, 5 or 10-degree intervals, depending on the test type. Send plane horizontally, create columns from 0-360, and similar intervals as verticals. An example dataset can be as follows:

[image: sample dataset]

I can read the file and populate values to a 2D array or list. However, I'm trying to figure out if there is an easier way to read a value referenced by a particular row and column with C#. I want to fetch the value from the 2D array where row = 3 degrees and col = 20 degrees. Note: Each file can have different angle steps for vertical and horizontal angles. Ex. one file can have 1-180 with 1-degree steps and another one with5-degreee steps. Similar goes for horizontals.

Comment: So your problem is the labeling of the rows and columns?

Comment: What is easier than?

Comment: depending on type of array either array[3][20] or array[3,20]  Column can be calculated by x/5 where x = 20.  where the data is variable the divisor is the number in row = 0 column 2.

Comment: @ZoharPeled, the simple answer is no. OK, the list of rows and columns where the test was conducted is included within the text file, the test results in a separate section of the file. Say if I want to find the value where row = 5 degrees, and col = 20 degrees, I need to load row and column data into a 1D array, find the corresponding indexes for both row and col, and then use a for loop iterate through the 2D value range again to find the match. Just checking if there is an easier and faster way to do this.

Comment: Not really sure I understand your description. Can you please edit your question to include sample data as a text table, and show what you've attempted so far?